# Java Scanner "rewind"

Tags: java, parsing

I'm using a Java Scanner object to parse a text file.
I would need to scan part of the file twice (for performance reasons so that I don't have to store its content temporarily).

Hence, is there an approach to "rewind" the Scanner to a specific file position?

Alternatively, is there a way to clone a scanner so that I can use independently each instance (i.e. they will not move each other's file position pointer)?

Many thanks,
Thomas

**EDIT:**

Scanning the file only once and processing it directly is obviously always possible but would create significant additional complexity in our existing code base, hence the need to scan twice the same portion of the file.

In a nutshell: the file contains thousands of logical items and to process some of them, I need to have from the item start an info that is stored at the end of the item.

Comment: What are your performance constraints? Is the text file gigantic? Otherwise it may be acceptably fast just to process it multiple times, and optimise when this becomes a problem.

Comment: How many GB is the file that it is more efficient to re-read it than save what you need? 10 GB, 100 GB, 1 TB?

Comment: You wouldn't use a Scanner. You'd use real file IO; either `RandomAccessFile` or NIO http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

Comment: @BrianRoach These libraries do make parsing text tricky

Answer (score 5):

Just create a new Scanner instance when you need one. There's no need or benefit to cloning it even if you could. Same for "re-winding" -- just create a new Scanner if you need to re-read the file. I would explore however storing the bits you need, as I'm sure that this would be more efficient.

As an aside: consider telling us more about your requirements and the reasoning behind any restrictions as this information can help us give you better answers.

Comment: Thx but how would the new scanner "point" to the same position in the file?

Comment: @Tom why not just tell us more about what it is exactly you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: Use skip or seek as appropriate.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: For `Scanner`, there is no `seek`, only `skip`, but `skip` is to be used with a `Pattern`. `Scanner` is not a `Reader`.

Comment: You need to skip or seek the underlying stream and read from there.  This means using a new Scanner in many cases as it is stateful.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey he wants to seek back, and have a scanner ready holding a state that matches the state a scanner previously achieved at that file position, and continue (re)scanning from that position. He wants to avoid re-parsing from the beginning to the target position altogether.

Comment: @TheBlastOne I don't believe he can do that, nor do I believe he should.  Really he should just parse the file once, extracting what he needs the first time.

Comment: Thanks all for the fruitfull suggestions. I will clarify a bit further my needs in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081017131128AAUcIow

> Java's Scanner doesn't have a file "rewind" method but you can get the same effect by closing the Scanner and reopening it

Comment: Thanks but what I actually need is a rewind to a particular file position (not to the start of the file). Cheers