# Java program to count lines, char, and words from a text file

Tags: java

My output for the number of words and char keeps giving me zero. If anyone could help me find the
error in my code that would be great. The code enclosed by the stars is the code given by our teacher
and we are required to put this in our program.

Thank you!

** Our teacher told us not to use the buffered method. Also if I changes the lineNum method would it still override other methods? 
 Part of the assignment is to use at least two methods in our program****

** I edited my code based on everyones advice** It is now printing the correct numbers! How can I implement my two methods within this? A suggestion was that I use the for loop for the wordCount method. 
**I also need help with counting number of paragraphs**
A good starting point?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WordStats1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("data.txt"));
        //int totalLines = lineNum(input);
        //int wordCount = wordCount(input); 
        //int countChar = countChar(input);


        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(
                "newfile.txt"));

        int lineNum = 0;
        int wordCount = 1;
        int charCount = 0; 

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line;
            line = input.nextLine();

            //output.println(lineNum + ": " + line);

            lineNum++;

            String str [] = line.split((" "));
              for ( int i = 0; i <str.length ; i ++) {
                if (str [i].length() > 0) {
                  wordCount ++; 
                }
              }
              charCount += (line.length());

        }

        System.out.println(lineNum);
        System.out.println(wordCount); 
        System.out.println(charCount); 
        input.close();
        output.close();

        System.out.print("File written.");

    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error opening one of the files.");
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do your linecount, word count and character count all inside a single loop. By having 3 functions, the very first function call to lineNum iterates over your scanner object, then the other two function calls return 0 because the scanner object has already read the file and as it is at the end of the file there is nothing left to read.

I would suggest you edit your teachers code, in particular the while loop. Remove the 3 functions and the corresponding function calls and have the program do all of your counting inside the loop inside the main() function.

```
int lineCount = 0;
int wordCount = 0;
int charCount = 0;
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
  // read a line from the input file
  String line = input.nextLine();

  // increment line count
  lineCount++;

  // split line into words and increment word count
  String str [] = line.split((" "));
  for ( int i = 0; i <str.length ; i ++) {
    if (str [i].length() > 0) {
      wordCount ++; 
    }
  }

  // increment char count
  charCount += (line.length());
}
```

**EDIT**

Given that you have said you need to use 2 methods, heres what I suggest:

Move the word counting code above (the for loop) into a function of its own, it takes a String argument (the current line) and returns an integer. You can keep calling this from inside the loop.

```
wordCount += countWordsInString(line);
```

Comment: Generally, when you receive code from a teacher they want you to use it as is. Reason being, it usually forces the student to learn or demonstrate certain knowledge. (Creating a new instance of the scanner for each loop, in this case)

Comment: That may be so, but as far as I can tell, there is a function called lineNum() that counts the lines and there is a loop in the main() function that counts the lines. So the teachers code either does the same thing twice or the student has already edited the code before putting it on SO. I'm guessing the latter, hence my suggestion to remove the 3 functions and just do it in the while loop.

Comment: So I modified my code above to fit your suggestion. Could you help me with calling the different methods because I tried to put the wordCount into a different method and it is giving me 0 again and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show me the code that you have currently? Just edit your question above, and put in the code.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that, once you've called `lineNum()`, you are at the end of the file. When `wordCount()` and `countChar()` call `hasNextLine()`, this returns `false` and the functions return zero.

For some ideas on how to rewind a `Scanner`, see [Java Scanner "rewind"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573790/java-scanner-rewind).

Comment: So should I add the loop which counts the number of lines should I include that in my word count and char count methods?

Comment: @user3546001: You could have a method that counts all three during a single pass over the input file. Alternatively (and less efficiently) you could perform three separate passes over the file, for example by re-creating the scanner object three times.

Comment: If the `main` function really must appear verbatim in your solution then you'll have to do something along these lines. I take issue with this assignment, though - much better would be to compute line, word, and character count in a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

The lineNum() method essentially 'consumes' the file, so input.hasNextLine() always returns false in the wordCount() and countChar() methods, hence you get zero in those two cases.

Either combine all three methods in one uber-counter and process the file once, or load the file into some temporary variable such as a string and pass that into the three methods.