# Why is it not possible to call the scanEverything method twice? It only prints out the arrayList once, and the second println shows an empty list

Tags: java

I have a **test1.txt** file in the same folder as the rest of the files. Say, for instance, it has the following data: Hello Hello Hello
My code only prints this once. I called the method twice, but the second println shows an empty arraylist.

**run:**

```
[hello, hello, hello]
[]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

**Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Text {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            String firstFileName = "test1.txt";
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(new File(firstFileName));

            
            System.out.println(scanEverything(scan1));
            System.out.println(scanEverything(scan1));
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> scanEverything(Scanner scan) {
        ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String nextWord = scan.next().toLowerCase();
            text.add(nextWord);
        }
        Collections.sort(text);
        return text;
    }
```

Comment: You only create one scanner, when it finishes reading the file it won't start again at the beginning, you would need to create a new scanner.

Comment: After the first scan, `scan.hasNext()` must be false, right? So the scanner has reached the end of the file. When you call `scanEverything` again, `scanHasNext` will still be false, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your call to scanEverything, the Scanner is "consumed", i.e. the `scan.hasNext()` will return false.

If you want to scan the file again, you have to recreate the Scanner (see here for details: [Java Scanner "rewind"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573790/java-scanner-rewind))

Answer (score 0):

Scanner that you defined as **"scan1"** got consumed after first function call you have to use **different Scanner** or close the first scanner that is **"scan1"** and initiate it again.

For eg.

After calling function **scanEverything** use below lines

```
scan1.close();
scan1 = new Scanner(new File(firstFileName));
```